# Evenly filling spaces for a specific average value

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, optimization, binary

Imagine I have $N$ spaces.  Each space can be empty, or occupied.  Given a fixed point value $x$ between zero and one, I would like to evenly populate the $N$ spaces such that $\frac{N_{\text{occupied}}}{N}$ is approximately equal to $x$.  The purpose of the even distribution is such that the average rate of encountering occupied spaces when traversing the spaces follows $x$.

I understand that $\left \lfloor{N \cdot x}\right \rfloor$ will give me the number of spots to fill.  But how do I algorithmically distribute them most evenly within the $N$ spaces?  Is there any way to do this "cleanly"?

I've considered doing this with a boolean pseudorandom number generator with mean $x$, but I'm worried that wouldn't give optimal reliability and precision.  Ideally the solution would not be very computationally intensive.  Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean by "evenly"?  Do you mean evenly spaced?  Note that most actually random sequences look kind of clumpy to the average person.

Comment: You might consider a "leaky bucket" token admission model.  Consider a bucket of size 1 that is initially empty.  A fluid pours into the bucket with rate $x$ over time $t \in [0, N]$.  Every time the bucket fills to an integer value, you release all of that in a burst.  The burst falls into the (integer) time slot associated with the current time.  That is, the interval $[0,N]$ is decomposed into $N$ subintervals $[0, 1)$, $[1, 2)$, ...,$[N-1,N]$. A burst that lands in one of these is like "occupying" that space.

Comment: Yes @BrianTung, I mean evenly distributed.   For example, if $x=0.5$ and $N=5$ the sequence could be $01010$.  This breaks down a bit once you start to deal with values which don't have whole number multiplicative inverses, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you @Michael, that's a great suggestion.  Unfortunately, due to the weird limits of my operating environment (synchronous hardware description), that method is somewhat impractical.  Interesting concept though...

Comment: @nanogru : Why would it be impractical?  For example if $x = 1/\pi$ then out of the spaces $\{1, 2, 3, ...\}$ you would occupy spaces $\{4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 26\}$ adn so on. Once you place a burst, it is easy to calculate when you should place another one.  You do not need to implement a fluid drain, you can do exactly the same thing in discrete steps. I am assuming you can do real-number arithmetic in hte hardware.

Comment: @Michael, I'm sorry you're absolutely correct (I need more coffee).  Thank you so much, and I think I will end up implementing your bucket suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p$ be the proportion that you want filled, i.e., $p = \frac{N_{occupied}}N$. Leave the first space empty if $p<1$; otherwise, fill it.

Now let $f(k) = \lfloor pk \rfloor - \lfloor p(k-1) \rfloor$ and observe that if $k \in \mathbb Z$, then $f(k) \in \{0,1\}$. Use $f(k)$ as an indicator for filling the spaces for $k>1$; that is, fill the $k$th space if and and only if $f(k)=1$.

---

Example: say $p=0.71$ and $N=10$. Here's a table with columns $\left(k, pk, \lfloor pk \rfloor, f(k)\right)$. As you can see, a total of seven spaces are filled, and $\frac{7}{10} \approx 0.71$.

```
 1  0.71    0   0  
 2  1.42    1   1  
 3  2.13    2   1  
 4  2.84    2   0  
 5  3.55    3   1  
 6  4.26    4   1  
 7  4.97    4   0  
 8  5.68    5   1  
 9  6.39    6   1  
10  7.10    7   1
```

Comment: (This effectively implements the "bucket model" mentioned in the comments above.)

Comment: minor typo in first paragraph: I think you meant "otherwise, if $p=1$, then fill it."

Comment: @Michael Thanks—fixed!

Comment: @nanogru The answer provided by Steve Kass may be slightly better than mine in that the proportion over time will be closer to $p$ (sometimes greater than $p$ and sometimes lesser). My method, on the other hand, guarantees that the proportion of a run starting from the first space will never be greater than $p$. It depends what your needs are.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. Generate the list of $N$ numbers $$\lfloor 0.5\rfloor, \lfloor x+0.5\rfloor, \lfloor 2x+0.5\rfloor,\dots,\lfloor (N-1)x+0.5\rfloor,$$ where $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ is the greatest integer function. Then “fill” box $k$ when $\lfloor kx+0.5\rfloor>\lfloor (k-1)x+0.5\rfloor$.

Note that this is equivalent to drawing the straight line from $(0,-0.5)$ to $(N-1,(N-1)x-0.5)$ on an integer grid and “filling” each column if the line passes through a horizontal grid line in this column. In the picture below, the line and it’s “floor” are drawn. You’d fill the boxes for the leftmost $x$-value of each segment of the floor function (orange), or boxes $2,5,9,12,15,19,22,25,29$, if $x=0.3$ and $N=30$.

[image]

This is like the “anti-aliasing” problem in computer graphics, where one needs to draw a slanted line using square pixels.